# Writing string to file after particular string

Tags: java, android

I want to write particular string in a file after a string. My file has this already -

```
##############################
path :
```

I need to write the String `/sdcard/Docs/MyData` after `path :`

Could anyone tell me how I could achieve this?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: Just use `MODE_APPEND` if there is already something in the file.

Comment: You can also take a look at [Random Access File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) if you have to read the `path :` string befor writing out its value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you mean to append your path at the end of your file.
If so the use of a `FileWriter` is a good way to do it.

```
new FileWriter("Your path", true)
```

Notice that the boolean `true` in this case indicates that you want to append to your file, removing this altogether or using `false` instead would mean you want to overwrite the file.

An example for your case:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/YourEpicPath/ThisFileNeedsSomeAppending.txt", true)))) {
    out.println("/sdcard/Docs/MyData");
}catch (IOException e1) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html) is some documentation if you need for android, normally there shouldn't be any big differences.

Comment: No actually my question was writing a String after a string. For example, writing "com.hi" after "path:". It should look like this path:com.hi